# find + delete folders with extension when using variable

Tags: linux, bash, rhel, find, rm

we have linux rhel machine 7.2 with the following folders under `/kafka/topics`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-10
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-100
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-103
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-106
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-109
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-112
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-115
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-118
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-121
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-124
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-127
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  kafka    141 May 11 17:19 bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-13
.
.
.
```

we want to delete all this topics with names - `bgol.ase.fgt.dad3` by using variable as ,

```
topic=bgol.ase.fgt.dad3
find /kafka/topics  -name "$topic*" -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```

but I feel the above approach isn't so elegant , since we want to set this approach in bash script

I will appreciate to get other suggestion to delete the folders , when using variable as $topic

Answer (score 1):

if you use find , it's return full path :

```
$ find /kafka/topics 
/kafka/topics/bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-1
/kafka/topics/bgol.ase.fgt.dad3-100
...
```

so , you should be add `*` after var and befor this var like that `*$topic*` , finallment

```
find /kafka/topics  -name "*$topic*" -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```